# Removing "QGIS ROCKS" text box?

Tags: qgis

I am adding property names to a property boundary shapefile using QGIS 2.8.2.

I don't know what I have done to get several "qgis rocks" text boxes on my screen.

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 9):

You've added text annotation to the map.

Click the Annotation button I've highlighted, can select each one, and delete them.

[image]

Comment: Since he seems to want to delete all the annotations, no need for the move annotation. Using the highlighted tool, he only needs click the above the anotation and press DEL.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto thanks! Why wasn't I able to get that to work before.. hmmm...

Comment: I have also just removed that text for the next version as it's not good having default text like that.

Comment: @NathanW make it say QGIS RULEZ!!!

Comment: @mapBaker well at least it's not a lie :P